# Add a simple field to django form without updating the model

Tags: python, django, checkbox

Django newbie here

I want to add a checkbox to django form, but this checkbox doesn't have to be stored in the database.

A trivial solution is to add it directly to the html template. But I want to keep the django format :

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

So I thought that I need to add the checkbox in the form class.

I did the following :

```
    class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
          ...
          check_box = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput)
```

But on the template I can't find the checkbox.
Any idea ? 
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't exist in my model, that's the point of my question. The checkbox is just ( I accept the terms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    accept_terms = forms.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
       model = YourModel
```

Comment: Didn't work :\ 
How do I debug {{form}} in template ?

Comment: @Sekai There really isn't much that could not work. Did you try restarting your server after making the change?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong template. 
Your solution works fine ! thanks a lot